# How to have the height of a popover change dynamically for iPad

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, popover

I have a popover/popup containing text and switches. The labels and switches are in a stackView which is inside a UIView. The stackView is constrained so that as the stackView changed size based upon its content the UIView also changes. When I change to another language say French, the text strings becomes longer which causes the labels in the popover to add a second line of text. This in turn makes the height for the popover get taller.

Here’s the issue:
As far as I know the height of the popover is set in the prepare for segue on the view that opens the popover (TallY_VC).  The new height of the popover is not determined until viewDidAppear runs in the code of the popover VC (Tallly_Popover_VC). So that means that the required height the popover needs to be is undetermined when prepare for segue runs.

For the iPhone the height is set automatically. Is there a way to make the height of the popover change automatically for iPad like it does for iPhone or is preferredContentSize the only way?

Below is the prepare for segue code in the TallY_VC view controller. This is the only way I could come up with to set the popover height for each language. I’m using Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first to get the current language and then manually setting the preferredContentSize height. This works but when I have 15 or 20 languages it’s going to be laborious. Thanks in advance.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Tally_Popover", bundle: nil)
        var popupVC: Tallly_Popover_VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Tallly_Popover") as! Tallly_Popover_VC
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popupVC)
        
        var preferredLang: String = "en"
        var theHeight: Int = 471
        
        let deviceName = UIDevice().type
        let deviceString: String = ("\(deviceName)")
        
        if segue.identifier == "tally_pop"
        {
            if deviceString.contains("iPad")
            {
                popupVC = segue.destination as! Tallly_Popover_VC
                
                preferredLang = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first ?? "en"
                
                if preferredLang == "fr"
                {
                    theHeight = 551
                    
                } else if preferredLang == "en" {
                    
                    theHeight = 471
                }
                
                popupVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 310, height: theHeight)
                navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
                
            } else if deviceString.contains("iPhone") {
                
                present(navigationController, animated: true)
                navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = false
            }
        }
    }
```